# How to use object as variable of class as ArrayList?

Tags: java, class, object, variables, arraylist

I've Course Class that conatains name, teacher, students[];

```
public class Course implements Comparable<Course> {
variables ...
private Student[] students;


public Course(variables... int maxStudents) {
variables...
this.maxStudents = maxStudents;
students = new Student[maxStudents];
}
```

I've courseGrades class

```
public class GradesList{
private Course course;
private ArrayList<Integer> grades;

public ListaOcen(Course course)
{
    this.course = course;
    grades = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

And also I've student class

```
public class Student extends Person {
variables...
private ArrayList<ListaOcen> degresList;

public Student(variables...) {
    super(variables...);
    course = new Course[5];
    degresList = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

I can't figure out, how exactly should I pass courseGrades class as variable of student class and how later on I can fill that grades list. So far I've created this function

```
public void addDeggre(Integer deggre) {
    if(deggre > 1 && deggre < 7)
        grades.add(deggre);
}
```

Comment: I would not have a cl;ass called CourseGrades. Instead, I would have a variable in Course that is a Map of <Student, Integer>

Comment: @FredK How would it work? this map would store Student object, and a integer(should'nt be array or arraylist?), but how would it work ?

Answer (score 0):

To use a map in the Course class, include :

```
   private TreeMap<Student, Integer> grades = new TreeMap<>();
   private ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then the Course class has a method to add a student, and to set the grade, and get the grade:

```
   public void addStudent( Student s ) {
      students.add(s);
      grades.put(s,0);
   }
   public void setGrade( Student s, int grade ) {
      grades.replace(s,grade);
   }
   public int getGrade( Student s ) {
      return grades.get(s).intvalue();
   }
```

Of course, you need to add code to handle errors, such as for setGrade() and getGrade() if the passed Student is not in the map.